# MS SQL Server - How to run a query one by one after a delay?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, delay

I would like to run a query and then 5 min break then after the next query.

How to do this with T-SQL in MS SQL Server?

**EDIT:**
I run a heavy query in production environment which takes about 10 min. and causes some delays on the system. In 5 min delay the system is relaxing and completes some jobs which are queued. And then I run the next heavy query..

Comment: What is wrong with the question? Why is downvoted?

Comment: Was wondering my self, i upvoted.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? You'll block a connection and accumulate locks for no reason. If you want to run a job every 5 minutes, use a SQL Server Agent job. Are you trying to synchronize execution with some other task?

Comment: Please see my edit in question. And also the comment below answer.

Comment: I have to say that if you just need to wait 5 minutes then there is something wrong with the system design in general. That kind of thing just doesn't make sense.

Comment: What is it that doesn't block your current query but keeps executing a full 5 minutes after you finish? Lots of temporary data, a big tempdb, large rollbacks, are all problems that should be fixed, now covered up with a delay

Comment: @SeanLange Here is wrong place to discuss the whole system design. If you want to understand how is my system please contact me ismailyavu@gmail.com Thanks..

Comment: LOL. What I am saying is that waiting for 5 minutes in the middle of a procedure is HIGHLY unusual. In the 20 years I have in the business I have never seen a situation where that makes good sense. And no I don't need to understand your system. I gave my opinion that what you are trying to do could be improved greatly by changing the process. Maybe the thing that needs attention is to improve the queries so they don't take down your system instead of finding a clever way to temporarily ease the pressure.

Comment: Last three years in this system this query was never required. And now they wanted this from me and I have to give them. Not a normal procedure or daily even yearly standard queries. Unexpexted work. This is a Vehicle Tracking System. I have something like 10 millions of rows for each day. Every row represents a location of a vehicle at a time. They wanted me to list "give us vehicles list which are sent one or more data in May, June and July of 2015". I have to scan all 900 million rows one by one! This causes some delay on our data process program.

Comment: @ismail yavuz: your description of the query is not very clear. Do you need a distinct list of vehicles which were in use during that three-month period? Don't you have a VehicleUseHeader and VehicleUseDetail relationship set up? You have only a transaction detail table, and no table that contains *trips*?  An index on VehicleID in a trip-header table would make the query possible without a full table scan.  An index on VehicleID even in the transaction detail table would allow that as well.

Comment: @Tim Simply I've two tables. One stores the last data of Vehicle. It has 10K rows: (longitude,latitude,vehicleId,address,dataDate...) and the other is vehicleLog which stores again same columns but all the old data and has billions of rows. It's partitioned day by day and has a clustered index on vehicleId,dataDate. If I knew this query would be required just copy of Vehicle table in the first second of the month that is enough. But I wish knew.. And know how to list distinct vehicleIds of all these rows without a full-scan?

Comment: Why do you have to look at this table one row at a time? Nowhere in your explanation do you mention what you are trying to do. I suspect the queries could be greatly optimized so you don't need to process this row by agonizing row.

Comment: I need to this for three months individually: select distinct vehicleId from vehicleLog where dataDate > '2015-05-01' and dataDate < '2015-05-31'

Comment: @ismail yavuz: Obviously the index is optimized for searches for particular vehicles. It would add overhead, but you could create a second index (dataDate, vehicleid) that would be optimized for selecting info for a date-range.

Comment: @Tim I've already clustered unique index with vehicleId,dataDate.. Because where clause's of normal queries depends on a few vehicle. And also the table partitioned by dataDate day by day. I think this is the best table structure for this program. But this unexpected query was hard for me. At the end of the day, whole 3 months query with these delays took less than 4 hours.. I am happy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT GETDATE() CurrentTime
WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:05' ---- 5 Second Delay
SELECT GETDATE() CurrentTime
```

ref: http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/01/03/sql-server-time-delay-while-running-t-sql-query-waitfor-introduction/

**EDIT**

As @Panagiotis Kanavos is said:
Any locks acquired by the first query will be kept until the entire batch completes.

If this is a problem in your situation try to create a SQL Agent JOB with two steps and add a WAITFOR DELAY step between both.

Comment: The 5 minute wait means that transactions, locks etc will remain open for 5 minutes for no reason. *Why* do you want to wait for 5 minutes? Even if there is a reason to wait 5 minutes, a SQL Server Agent job would be the way to do this

Comment: See my edit for why question. No. One of my query is terminating, then the wait starts and after the next query starts to run. No lock. It is simpler than create SQL Server Agent jobs. And how can you say "wait 5 minutes after the first step before the second step" to SQL Agent? Of course with a "waitfor delay" step between them again :)

Comment: Locks are acquired by the server while your query executes and are kept until the transaction they were created in (or the connection) is closed. Any locks acquired by the first query will be kept until the entire batch completes. A step with a single WAITFOR is completely different - it's a separate connection with no transactions/locks

Comment: I've updated the answer based on your comment. Thanks.